# Jquery ignoring variable on if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a small jquery script that tests if any number has been entered in a field while typing. If it has not, a warning box appears below the field with .after() , if the someone types a number -> the warning box will dissapear.

The script works fine, but I can't get it to only run the .after() once. It completely ignores my "displayed" variable because I am obviously doing something wrong. The result is in the .after() running for each non-number character typed in the input field and a bunch of warning boxes appear.

```
$("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").on("input", function() {
  var val = $("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").val();
  var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
  var displayed = false;

  if ((matches == null) && (displayed != true)) {
    displayed = true;
    $("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").after("<div class='number-warning' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(229, 148, 0); color: rgb(229, 148, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 246, 229);'>Geen huisnummer opgegeven</p>");
    return false;
  } else {
    $(".number-warning").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why repeat `#checkout_shipping_address_address1` every time. Just put it in a variable and/or use `$(this)` while in the input handler callback scope.

Comment: Thank you for noticing I will fix that.

Comment: Your match doesn't return null if text input has at least 1 number. If you want to get match for each pressed key then use onkeypress.

Comment: You should consider expanding the scope of your regex to include letters AND numbers. This way the input must contain both and will throw an error if this condition isn't met.

    Example:  /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
      var displayed = false;
      var val = $("#checkout_shipping_address_address1");
      $(val).on("input", function() {
        var valmatches = $(val).val();
        var matches = valmatches.match(/\d+/g);
          if ( (matches == null) && (displayed == false) ) {
              displayed = true;
              $(val).after("<div class='number-warning' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(229, 148, 0); color: rgb(229, 148, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 246, 229);'>Geen huisnummer opgegeven</p>");

          } if ( (matches != null) && (displayed == true) ) {
            displayed = false;
              $(".number-warning").hide();

          }
      });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if-else` construct was not quite right, it would have hidden the warning each time a number *was* matched. I changed that and also I changed the event in the `on` function to `keyup` as this will fire after each key release.

```
$("#checkout_shipping_address_address1").on("keyup",function() {
var matches= $(this).val().match(/\d+/g);
if (matches == null) {
  if ($('.number-warning').show().length==0){
     $(this).after("<div class='number-warning' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 7px; margin-top: 5px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(229, 148, 0); color: rgb(229, 148, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 246, 229);'>Geen huisnummer opgegeven</p>");
  return false;}
 } else {
   $(".number-warning").hide();
 }
});
```

I also added the `show()` method into the script for the case, that a previously added warning label still exists but needs to be reactivated, because of the `match`-condition. In this case it just needs to be "`show()`n" but not appended again.

Generally it is not a very good idea to include the `.append()` part into the input checking part. It would be better to define it once and then just hide or show it.